# Assistance with using .map

Tags: reactjs

How can I use .map so I can get the data for rentals and display the movie title as well? Do I use two .map functions or do I have to use a useEffect?

1. Movies

   - Id
   - Name
   - Price
2. Rentals

   - Id
   - Movie Id
   - Date Rented
   - Customer email

```
const RentalPage = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [rentals, setRentals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRentals(setRentals);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(setMovies);
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Customer Email</th>
                <th>Movie Title</th>
                <th>Purchase Date</th>
                <th>Price</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {rentals.map((rental) => (
              <tbody key={rental.id}>
                <tr>
                  <td>{rental.customerEmail}</td>
                  <td >{movie.movieTitle}</td> <----------- (How do I use .map to get movie name)
                  <td>{rental.purchaseDate}</td>
                  <td>{rental.price}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            ))}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My question is since I am already using .map, can I use it again with different data without changing the database?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a .map there. .map is used to display the whole array. What I would do in your situation is use .find on movies like: `<td>{movies.find(movie => movie.id === rental.movieId).moveTitle}</td>`  in the `<td>` where your comment is pointing. Also you should put both of your fetches in one useEffect - no difference just less code and easier to read.

Comment: I tried this and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` or `filter`

```
{rentals.map((rental) => {
    // find
    const movie_title = movies.find(movie => movie.id === rental.movieId).movieTitle
    // or by filter 
    let _movie_title = movies.filter(movie => movie.id === rental.movieId)[0].movieTitle
    return <tbody key={rental.id}>
        <tr>
            <td>{rental.customerEmail}</td>
            <td >{movieTitle}</td>
            <td>{rental.purchaseDate}</td>
            <td>{rental.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
})}
```

`find` returns the element that matches in the criteria, and `filter` returns a sublist of items that matched the criteria.

Comment: I’m getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘movieTitle’). How can I fix this? It renders the page sometimes and other times it doesn’t.

Comment: When you're component first mounts it hasn't fetched the data yet, so when you ```find``` your movie title it isn't there yet (im assuming this is what is happening). Lot's of things you can do, if the only problem is the movie title ```let movie_title = movies.map(movie => movie.id).includes(rental.movieId) ? movies.find(movie => movie.id === movieId).movieTitle : 'Default Movie Title'```  Something like that.